# Decompose $f = x^3 - x^2 \in Z_2$ in a product of irreducible polynomials

Tags: polynomials

$$x^3 - x^2 = x^2(x-1)$$

So, after reaching this point, $x-1$ is surely an irreducible polynomial because $gr(x-1) = 1$, but how to continue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can decompose $X^2$ as $X \cdot X$. And $X$ also has degree $1$ and is thus irreducible.

The decomposition is thus $X \cdot X \cdot (X-1)$.

Comment: Ahh, I thought about this during the exercise but I thought it was not the proper way to solve it. Thanks though :)